# More efficient way of storing variables to a map by splitting a text file

Tags: java

I'm currently making a social media app that contains profile details such as interests in a text file. The following code works by using markers in the text file to upload these details to map data structures. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

```
textList = ReadFile(FileName);
    System.out.println("File Length" + textList.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < textList.size(); i++){
        String[] split = splitTxt(textList.get(i), "\\s+");
        List<String> friends = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> interests = new ArrayList<>();
        if (split.length >= 2){
            String[] interestArray = splitTxt(split[2], ";");
            for(int j = 0; j < interestArray.length; j++){
                interests.add(interestArray[j]);
            }
            Accounts.put(split[0],split[1]);
            intrestDic.put(split[0],interests);
            for(int j= 3; j < split.length; j++){
                friends.add(split[j]);

            }
            FriendsDic.put(split[0],friends);
            System.out.println(FriendsDic.get(split[0]));
        }

    }
```

I've created a split function that looks for marker to split it on.

```
public static String[] splitTxt(String text, String type){
    String[] parsedText = text.split(type);
    return parsedText;
}
```

Comment: I think [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) will be a good site for this question. This site is not for reviewing already working code, check the appended link.

Comment: If this code works fine, you should submit it on our sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Get rid of the split function. It's really only a one-liner. Don't read the entire file into memory first: process it a line at a time. However none of this is likely to be any kid of a bottleneck unless you have tens of millions of lines. Don't guess where your hotspots are: measure.